# How to sort list within a list?

Tags: python

I want to sort my list based on the first item such as:

```
fruits = \
[['Mango', 6, 5, 8.0],
 ['Banana', 2.0, 5, 8.9, 7],
 ['Pineapple', 4, 6.8, 9],
 ['Apple', 3.9, 6, 7, 2]]
```

to be sorted out like this:

```
fruits = \
[['Apple', 3.9, 6, 7, 2],
 ['Banana', 2.0, 5, 8.9, 7],
 ['Mango', 6, 5, 8.0],
 ['Pineapple', 4, 6.8, 9]]
```

I know I have to use `sort()` function but I don't know how to use it in a right way to produce the outputs that I want.

Comment: Are the first elements of the lists strings?

Comment: @Volatility most definitely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is your problem exactly? `sort()` already sorts by the first element.

```
In [14]: fruits = [["Mango", 6,5,8.0],
         ["Banana", 2.0,5,8.9,7],
         ["Pineapple", 4,6.8,9],
         ["Apple", 3.9,6,7,2]]

In [15]: fruits.sort()

In [16]: fruits
Out[16]: 
[['Apple', 3.9, 6, 7, 2],
 ['Banana', 2.0, 5, 8.9, 7],
 ['Mango', 6, 5, 8.0],
 ['Pineapple', 4, 6.8, 9]]
```

If your items are classes or variables, you should implement their comparison methods (`__ge__`, `__le__`, `__gt__`, `__lt__`) accordingly to your sorting needs.

Keep in mind that `fruits.sort()` modifies the list in place, if you want a new sorted copy, use `sorted(fruits)`

Comment: good point... I forgot that for a second

Comment: @fortran how can I miss something like this? I am a really python noob. Thanks for this!

Comment: well, it happens... Python excels in clarity most of the time, but in this case a global function like `sorted` or a list method `sort` can be confusing.